# 'noneType' and 'str' are unsupported operand types. What is causing this TypeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I'm getting this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

```
    return summary + "They work on the " + ProductionWorker.SHIFT[self.__shift] + " and make " + "$" \
           + str(format(self.__hourly_pay, "0.2f")) + " an hour."
```

Comment: I'd say summary, ProductionWorker.SHIFT[self.__shift] or self.__hourly_pay is None

Answer (score 0):

It means that one of the variables is `None`, which cannot be added to a `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Either summary or ProductionWorker.SHIFT[self.__shift] is None, but it is kinda hard to tell without knowing the rest of the code. 
Add a

```
print(summary,ProductionWorker.SHIFT[self.__shift])
```

before the return and see what's what.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'ProductionWorker' object has no attribute '_ProductionWorker__shift'`

Comment: The rest of my code is here if you want to look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47210455/how-do-i-change-a-superclass-attribute-thats-inside-of-a-subclass/47210638#47210638

Comment: @MCAbstract this code does not include your employeeclass and there are several other problems with it so i can't test it. Still, i don't see how you should get a no attribute error from that. Have you changed your code from the answers you got from this question? If so, repost the actual code you are using.